# forming a specific list with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'am currently working in a java project which I have a list of strings and I want them to have a specific format using streams .

For example

Input : `[nom, contains, b, and, prenom, contains, y, and, age, >=, 1, and, age, <=, 100]`
Ouput:

```
[
{key:"nom",
operation:"contains",
value:"b"
},
{
key:"prenom",
operation:"contains",
value:"y"
},
{
key:"age",
operation:">=",
value: 1
},
{
key:"age",
operation:"<=",
value: 1000
}]
```

I wrote a very basic code without using streams:

```
List filter = [nom, contains, b, and, prenom, contains, y, and, age, >=, 1, and, age, <=, 100]
    List<SearchCriteria> formedFilter = new ArrayList<>();
    SearchCriteria sc = new SearchCriteria();
    if(filter != null){
        for(int i = 0 ;i< filter.size();i++){
            if(i % 4 ==0){
                sc.setKey((String) filter.get(i));
            }else if(i % 4 == 1){
                sc.setOperation((String) filter.get(i));

            }else if(i % 4 ==2){
                sc.setValue(filter.get(i));
                formedFilter.add(sc);

            }else{
                sc = new SearchCriteria();
            }
        }
    }
```

SearchCriteria Class

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;

    public SearchCriteria() {
    }

    public SearchCriteria(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }

   // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Are the elements at index 3, 7 and 11 always `and`, or could they also be i.e. `or`, or maybe another boolean operation?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner they could be `and / or` but for the moment i don't need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Java 8 version of [Aomine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431169/1746118) you can use:

```
List<SearchCriteria> formedFilter = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 4)
            .limit(filter.size() / 4 + 1) // + 1 to consider the last group as well
            .mapToObj(i -> new SearchCriteria(filter.get(i), filter.get(i + 1), filter.get(i + 2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Alternatively, similar to a suggestion by Holger, you can use the `rangeClosed` API from IntStream as:

```
List<SearchCriteria> formedFilter2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, filter.size() / 4)
        .map(i -> i * 4)
        .mapToObj(i -> new SearchCriteria(filter.get(i), filter.get(i + 1), filter.get(i + 2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: By the way, since the placement of `limit` is irrelevant here, I’d chain it immediately to `iterate`, as that’s semantically closer and makes it easier to understand the iteration logic.

Comment: @Holger I just kept the short-circuiting closer to the terminal operation and the order wouldn't really matter here is what my understanding is.

Comment: @nullpointer right, as I said, the placement of `limit` is irrelevant here, so it’s just a matter of style. I see your point in emphasizing the result list’s size, but still think, the iteration logic is more important (consider the appearance of the `4`).

Comment: @WassimMakni Yeah, you're right, that's because I considered the operations to be a group of 4 strings while your case would have one less for the last operation.

Comment: @nullpointer I think that replacing `.limit(filter.size() / 4 + 1)` with `.limit(filter.size() / 4 + 1)` do the job correctly

Comment: @WassimMakni true, also a cleaner way could be as suggested by Holger as well using `range..` API

Answer (score 2):

Using JDK 9, you can do:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < source.size(), i -> i + 4)
         .mapToObj(x -> new SearchCriteria(source.get(x), source.get(x + 1), source.get(x + 2)))
         .collect(toList());
```

Comment: @WassimMakni it’s not working for Java 8, but you can replace `iterate(0, i -> i < source.size(), i -> i + 4)` with `range(0, source.size()/4).map(i -> i*4)`, which might even turn out to be more efficient.